# 100% bar chart SQL - Yes/No Answers

Tags: reporting-services, bar-chart

Sql Server 2016/Report Designer:

Not sure if this is the right title to place this question under so please correct me if I am wrong.

I have the following:

```
 SELECT [aField6] AS [CleanAndTidy],
        [aField10] AS [HandWash],
        [aField8] AS [PPEStorage],
        [aField14] AS [PipesAndFittings],
        [aField12] AS [COSHH]
 FROM vAdvF_265
 GROUP BY [aField6], [aField10], [aField8], [aField14], [aField12]
```

The answers come out as:

```
CleanAndTidy    HandWash    PPEStorage  PipesAndFittings    COSHH
No                 No            No           No            No
No                 Yes           Yes          Yes           Yes
Yes                No            No           Yes           Yes
Yes                No            Yes          Yes           Yes
Yes                Yes           No           No            Yes
Yes                Yes           No           Yes           No
Yes                Yes           Yes          No            No
Yes                Yes           Yes          Yes           No
Yes                Yes           Yes          Yes           Yes
```

I am looking to get this into a 100% stacked bar chart per column (50/50 on yes/no), but when using this in SSRS I can't seem to find the correct way of providing the data to the chart.

I have also tried:

```
    SELECT [Type1], [Count] -- YES Count
 FROM (
 SELECT 
     SUM(CASE WHEN [aField6]='yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [CleanAndTidyYes],
     SUM(CASE WHEN [aField10]='yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [HandWashYes],
     SUM(CASE WHEN [aField8]='yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [PPEStorageYes],
     SUM(CASE WHEN [aField14]='yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [PipesAndFittingsYes],
     SUM(CASE WHEN [aField12]='yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [COSHHYes]
     FROM vAdvF_265
 ) sums
 UNPIVOT
 ([Count] FOR [Type1] IN
     ([CleanAndTidyYes], [HandWashYes], [PPEStorageYes], [PipesAndFittingsYes], [COSHHYes])
 ) AS unpivoted1

 UNION

 SELECT [Type], [Count] --NO Count
 FROM (
 SELECT 
     SUM(CASE WHEN [aField6]='no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [CleanAndTidyNo],
     SUM(CASE WHEN [aField10]='no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [HandWashNo],
     SUM(CASE WHEN [aField8]='no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [PPEStorageNo],
     SUM(CASE WHEN [aField14]='no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [PipesAndFittingsNo],
     SUM(CASE WHEN [aField12]='no' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [COSHHNo]
     FROM vAdvF_265
 ) sums
 UNPIVOT
 ([Count] FOR [Type] IN
     ([CleanAndTidyNo], [HandWashNo], [PPEStorageNo], [PipesAndFittingsNo], [COSHHNo])
 ) AS unpivoted1;
```

Which gives me:

```
Type1                                                                                                                            Count
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -----------
CleanAndTidyNo                                                                                                                   2
CleanAndTidyYes                                                                                                                  18
COSHHNo                                                                                                                          3
COSHHYes                                                                                                                         17
HandWashNo                                                                                                                       7
HandWashYes                                                                                                                      13
PipesAndFittingsNo                                                                                                               2
PipesAndFittingsYes                                                                                                              18
PPEStorageNo                                                                                                                     4
PPEStorageYes                                                                                                                    16
```

Although the second one gives me the counts I am after, I am still struggling to get this into a 100% chart vs Yes/No answers for each column.

Could someone help point me in the right direction/offer any advice or other methods?

Answer (score 0):

Add an expression for bar graph value. In the expression add code like:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!CleanAndTidy.Value = "Yes", 1, 0))
```

The sum function will add the total values for every row in the dataset. You can then add the IIF expression inside to evaluate each column and return a value based on the expression. In the above example, if CleanAndTidy is "Yes", then 1 is returned. If not, 0 is returned. The end result will be the count of "Yes" answers.

You can then rinse and repeat for HandWash, etc. Rinse and repeat? Get it?